# Can Apple Pay support credit card stored in a different system other than Passport?

Tags: applepay

Can Apple Pay support credit card stored in a different system other than Passport? Are APIs available to build a custom backend solution similar to Passport that can be used by Apple Pay? What is the complexity to build such a custom backend system?

Comment: in addition to above question there is one more question Can we change default credit card by programmatically ? Is there any other way to change the default card programmatically ?